# remove spaces or tab when spooling

Tags: oracle

I am trying to extract data(spooling) from oracle and it got spaces or tab between the data.

My script is like this.

```
set head off;
set feed off;
set lines 32767;
set trimspool on;
set trimout on;
set pages 0;
set space 0;
set tab off;
set wrap off;
set colsep "|";
spool FNAME;
select select id, name, job from table;
spool off;
exit
```

The data should be like this:
ID|NAME    |JOB

Suppose ID and NAME should not have any spaces or tab between it
but instead, i have data like this:
ID<--spaces/tab-->|NAME      |JOB

There's additional spaces or tab added between ID and NAME. i already set the parameters. I dont know what to change.

Answer (score 0):

SQL*Plus is formatting the results into aligned columns for you. You can avoid this by doing the formatting yourself:

```
select select id || '|' || name || '|' || job from table;
```